# PEP8 compliant way to toggle logging for a whole package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a package with this structure :

```
mypackage
    |
    +---- a.py
    +---- b.py
    +---- __init__.py
```

this package is sometimes used as a library, sometimes as interactively with IPython, so I need to configure logging differently in both cases:

- interactively: print logs in the console, so the loggers should have a `StreamHandler` handler
- library: let the user configure logging, so the loggers should have a `NullHandler` handler

In `__init__.py` I do this:

```
import logging
import a
import b

logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())    

def get_loggers():
    """
    Get all the logger objects instantiated for the current package
    """
    loggers = []
    for logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.values():
        if not isinstance(logger, logging.Logger):
            continue
        if logger.name.startswith(__name__):
            loggers.append(logger)
    return loggers


def enable_logs():
    """
    Configure loggers to print on stdout/stderr
    """
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(name)s :: %(levelname)s :: %(message)s'))
    for logger in get_loggers():
        logger.removeHandler(handler)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.propagate = False


def disable_logs():
    """
    Configure loggers not to print anywhere
    """
    handler = logging.NullHandler()
    for logger in get_loggers():
        logger.removeHandler(handler)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.propagate = False
```

`a.py` and `b.py` both start with:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

So now I can enable/disable logging by doing this:

```
import mypackage
mypackage.enable_logs()
mypackage.disable_logs()
```

But this solution is not `PEP8` compliant because in `__init__.py` I import modules that are not used. Note that don't have to import them, but I want because then their respective loggers are created when I import the package.

Question1: Is their a PEP8 compliant way to achieve what the same goal?

Question2: This is subjective perhaps, is being PEP8 compliant worth it in this case?

Comment: I'd follow PEP20: _Although practicality beats purity._

Comment: Where exactly does PEP8 say this is not allowed?

Comment: @SimeonVisser actually pylint is saying `W0611 'a' imported but unused`. I assumed it was a PEP8 thing, but maybe it's not actually =/ I'm using vim with python-mode, this is were I get the error from, fwiw.

Comment: Correction: `pyflakes` is throwing the error. And there is actually a discussion about the validity of the error here https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyflakes/+bug/1178905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call this function at the beginning of your enable and disable logs functions to load the modules dynamically, but I think getting around the PEP this way may be cheating:

```
import glob
import imp
import os

def load_modules(module_names=None):
    if module_names is None:
        cur_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        module_wc = '{}/*.py'.format(cur_dir)
        module_names = [mn for mn in glob.glob(module_wc) if not mn.startswith('_')]
    modules = map(imp.load_source, module_names)
    return modules
```